# FormControl: Manually set error (and trigger to update the view)

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to implement a custom async validation with reactive forms (the built in one doesn't work for me because it triggers too many requests (also when another field changes)).

So therefore I implemented a manual way like this:

```
public validateUniquePolicyNumber(formControl: FormControl): void {

        const policyNumber = formControl.value;

        if (policyNumber != null || policyNumber.length > 0 ) {
            this.caseListService.validatePolicyNumber(policyNumber).subscribe( (res: any) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    let error: ValidationErrors = (res && res.policyNumberExists) ? res : null;
                    formControl.setErrors(error);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Now when I debug the `formControl` I see that it's invalid, but it doesn't update the view! Only when I do a focusout AGAIN (with the same value), it marks the field as invalid in the view.
I assume this is because `formControl.updateOn` is set to `change`, so it only triggers a view update on change. 
I did not find any way to update the view manually.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: can you please share html